# C++ Map of Vector of Structs?

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

So here's a snippet of my code:

```
    struct dv_nexthop_cost_pair
    {
      unsigned short nexthop;
      unsigned int cost;
    };
```

```
map<unsigned short, vector<struct dv_nexthop_cost_pair> > dv;
```

I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `map' with no type
```

What's the proper way to declare this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either you forgot to #include the right headers or didn't import the `std` namespace. I suggest the following:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

std::map<unsigned short, std::vector<struct dv_nexthop_cost_pair> > dv;
```

Comment: Yup... I forgot the includes. Sorry, C++ newb here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use typedef

```
typedef std::map<unsigned short, std::vector<struct dv_nexthop_cost_pair> > dvnexthopemap;
dvnexthopemap db;
```